# Magento can not set/edit product sort number since upgrade

Tags: magento, position, product

ever since we upgrade to Magento 1.14 when you go to Catalog ->Manage category -?category product tabs the position field is no longer  editable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all clarify the version of your Magento store, you have EE.
Now there are many reasons for something to break after upgrade, start by looking at the logs to get a better idea. Delete any old logs and refresh the categories backend.
Also good idea is if you have a backup rename the app/design/adminhtml/default folder and rollback the previous version.
Or try folder by folder to locate what file creates this issue.
For example rename and switch app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog with the old one , test etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you still need this but I ran into same problem today :).

If you don't have the position field available for edition is it more likely you have the module **OnTap_Merchandiser** installed, take a look into its configuration under `System / Configuration / Catalog / Visual Merchandising Options`, you can enable it there.

If the module is installed, you can also check on category management page the tab **Visual Merchandiser**, there you can specify sort order for your products.